# :first-of-type acting as if it doesn't exist?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am using `:first-of-type` pseudo class to remove a margin although its behaving as if im not using `first-of-type` at all and removes the margin on all the elements.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<ul id="share" class="hidden-xs">
        <li><a href="#" class="twitter-share socialicon" title="Share on Twitter"><em class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></em><div class="sr-only">Share on Twitter</div></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="instagram-share socialicon" title="Share on Instagram"><em class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></em><div class="sr-only">Share on Instagram</div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="envelope-share socialicon" title="Share via Email"><em class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></em><div class="sr-only">Share via Email</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.socialicon {
    margin-left: 80px;
    font-size: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.socialicon:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0px;
}


ul#share{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 19px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
ul#share li{
    display: inline-block;
}
ul#share li span {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n803qa54/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:first-of-type` is not exactly intuitive in what it does - it does not take the entire document into account, but takes the parent element as reference point. In that sense, each of your anchor elements is the "first element of its type" within the enclosing `li` element and that's why the selector is applied on each of those elements. What you instead have to do is move the `:first-of-type` one level down to the `li` element. Since they are all on the same level, only the first `li` is affected. (However, this would affect the first `li` in another list on the same page as well).

```
li:first-of-type .socialicon{
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

[your modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n803qa54/1/)